# Redis Cache failed in setInterval - Node js

Tags: node.js, redis, setinterval

I have function like below

```
const checkData = async()=>{
    let heroList: any = await redisClient.getValue("hero");
    heroList = JSON.parse(heroList);

    if(heroList.name  === "JBM"){
        return Promise.reject("deplicate record")
    }
    return heroList

}
```

usually it working fine but I tried to find how accurate this function so  to test this function, I used **`setTinterval`**

```
setInterval(async () => {
    await this.checkData()
})

setInterval(async () => {
    await this.checkData()
})
```

Here  **`setInterval`** function is duplicated. The **`IF`** condition broke 3 times for each setInterval function.

so I wonder here I missed enything or my approach is wrong or is there any better solution.